# Emulate Slack team model in MongoDB/MongooseJS

Tags: javascript, security, mongoose, permissions, ecmascript-6

I want to make a data model and schemas that look similar to Slack's Team settings (https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/201314026-Roles-and-permissions-in-Slack), where there are several roles a user can have, each level with higher permissions. In turn each role can perform certain actions with the highest level being able to do all and the lowest role having minimal, read-only access to only portions of the team.

How would I emulate a similar schema in MongooseJS? For example, if I had a schema for Organizations:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const options = {
  "collection": "organizations"
};

const organizationSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, default: '', unique: true },
  members:   [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  created: { type: Date, required: false, default: Date.now },
  updated: { type: Date, required: false, default: Date.now }
}, options);
```

For each role should I have a separate field, such as `owners`, `guests`, etc, and from there, how would I go about defining what that role could access and what actions it could perform? I'm looking for a specific implementation solution that maximizes security while allowing for clear separation of roles and permissions.

Edit:

I realized later that what we're talking about is a combination of RBAC (Role Based Access Control) and team context, so really what I want is a way to implement Team based RBAC where the users roles change based on the context of the team they're currently in.